# RemoteObjectManager и получение информации о тайлах

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть ли какой-нибудь метод, который получает тайл(ы) со всей информацией о нем?
Нашел метод **getTileUrl()**, но он возращает именно *url*.
Также не очень понял, что делает метод **getUrlTemplate()**.
Оба метода возвращаеют *url*.

Comment: О какой информации речь? Какую задачу хотите решить этим методом?

Comment: Надо получать имена видимых тайлов в таком виде - 12012121123  
После получения надо брать все видимые тайлы на этом зуме и отправлять на бэк.

Comment: За основу брал изначально этот код - https://github.com/theKashey/quadLoader , но он неправильно высчитывает имена тайлов, плюс создается впечатление, что нужный мне тайл находится на 1-4 порядка выше.

Comment: Всё же какая у вас задача? Для отображения данных достаточно использовать [UrlTemplate](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/RemoteObjectManager-docpage/#RemoteObjectManager__param-urlTemplate). В документации подробнее: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/remote-object-manager/about-docpage/

Comment: Отображение кластеров. С этим проблема возникает, т.к. на определенном зуме некоторые кластеры находятся на пересечении тайлов. Из-за этого они могут не отрисоваться, пока не поменять зум или позицию карты. Поэтому придумали способ - надо получить видимые тайлы и отправлять их на бэк для дальнейшей отрисовки. Собственно, надо получить имя видимого(ых) тайла(ов) в том виде, в которым скинул выше.

Comment: В urlTemplate есть %t подстановка которая заменяется на тайлы, почему она вам не подходит? https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/RemoteObjectManager-docpage/#RemoteObjectManager__param-urlTemplate